# Fast, reliable focus score for camera frames

Tags: ios, focus, camera, computer-vision

I'm doing real-time frame-by-frame analysis of a video stream in iOS.

I need to assign a score to each frame for how in focus it is. The method must be very fast to calculate on a mobile device and should be fairly reliable.

I've tried simple things like summing after using an edge detector, but haven't been impressed by the results. I've also tried using the focus scores provided in the frame's metadata dictionary, but they're significantly affected by the brightness of the image, and much more device-specific.

What are good ways to calculate a fast, reliable focus score?

Comment: Do you want a focus score that works (i.e. increases with better focus) within one video, or one that works across all frames in all video's? Anything edge based should work (after some tuning) for the first case. I don't know if the second case is even solved yet. (meaning: I don't know if an image independent focus measure exists)

Comment: @jilles The latter, I fear. The motivation is: The phone focuses *very* slowly. Waiting for it to finish focusing takes too long, so I want to stop it early, but I still need it to be at least moderately focused. Thus the need for a score I can monitor, and take action once it reaches a pre-defined threshold.

Comment: Maybe you can measure the rate of improvement of some sharpness and stop when it starts leveling off? So look at the first derivative of the sharpness rather than at the sharpness itself?

Comment: @jilles interesting. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a theoretical point of view, blur manifests as a lost of the high frequency content. Thus, you can just use do a FFT and check the relative frequency distribution. iPhone uses ARM Cortex chips which have NEON instructions that can be used for an efficient FFT implementation.

@9000's suggestion of heavily compressed JPEG has the effect of taking a very small number of the largest wavelet coefficients will usually result in what's in essence a low pass filter.

Answer (score 3):

Poor focus means that edges are not very sharp, and small details are lost. High JPEG compression gives very similar distortions.

Compress a copy of your image heavily, unpack and calculate the difference with the original. Intense difference, even at few spots, should mean that the source image had sharp details that are lost in compression. If difference is relatively small everywhere, the source was already fuzzy.

The method can be easily tried in an image editor. (No, I did not yet try it.) Hopefully iPhone has an optimized JPEG compressor already.

Comment: That's a really interesting suggestion! I'm not sure I could do this at 10 fps on an iPhone, even with the heavily optimized JPEG compressor, but I'll certainly give it a whirl. (I prototype everything in Python, and this should indeed be very easy to test.)

Comment: You can cut several reasonably small pieces from semi-random parts of the frame, and test on them. E.g. assume a 8x8 grid and only sample one random 1x1 piece in every 2x2 square. This way you'll need to compress far smaller amount of pixels. You'll get few false positives when all sharp areas are not in the parts you test. But since the test rectangles cover the frame evenly and randomly, the chance look slim.

Comment: A poor-mans version of this (in processing time) would be to reduce the image resolution by a factor of two (each pixel becomes the average of 4 pixels) then increase it by two (each pixel becomes a block of four) and calculate the average sum of squared differences between this image and the original. Properly optimized this can be done in place (without extra buffer image(s))

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer that human visual system probably uses is to implemnt focusing on top of edge
Tracking. Thus if a set of edges can be tracked across a visual sequence one can work with intensity profile
Of these edges only to detrmine when it the steepest.

Answer (score 0):

Consider different kind of edges: e.g. peaks versus step edges. The latter will still be present regardless of focus. To isolate the former use non max suppression in the direction  of gradient. As a focus score use the ratio of suppressed edges at two different resolutions.